# how to create a SSL Secure Connection using django 

Tags: python, django, ssl

I want to  send data using ssl for  data network Security when sending data ,

but how to make a ssl Secure Connection using django ,

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is not a django question.

SSL for a website is done on the web server, not your application, so you'd be setting up SSL in Apache or Nginx. Is that what you're looking to do?

If you mean you want to send data to some server via an SSL from within django, then it's a Python question about making SSL connections and stuff I'm not very familiar with : )

https://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

https://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html